# How to make main as client dll and logger class should run as service

Tags: c#-2.0

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace clogger
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CLogger.Trace("my class");
            CLogger.Error("message");
            CLogger.Warning("war");

```
    }
}
```

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace clogger
{
    class CLogger
    {
        static FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\vijay\mcb.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        static StreamWriter m_streamwriter = new StreamWriter(fs);

```
    public static void Trace(string p)
    {
        m_streamwriter.WriteLine("Trace(string p)");


    }

    public static void Error(string p)
    {
        m_streamwriter.WriteLine("Error(string p)");
        m_streamwriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        m_streamwriter.WriteLine("File writer operation starts: ");
        m_streamwriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());

    }

    public static void Warning(string p)
    {
        m_streamwriter.WriteLine("Warning(string p)");
        m_streamwriter.Flush();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking into logging with .Net, check out [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) (and custom TraceListener if you don't want to make your code dependent on 3rd party software). Log4Net is an opensource project and is used a lot when it comes to logging. I found [this](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-1-Getting-Started.aspx) tutorial quite help full though the official site will also provide you with a lot of information, I found this easier to get started. By the way a great plus of Log4Net in my opinion is that if you ever decide you want to log to an xml file it's a simple change in your app.config i.e. no writing of additional code.

Why do you want to run your logger as a service? If you only write to a local Txt file l4n will do the job and otherwise you can still write your own remote appender and then write a socketlistener or wcf udp listener that will write your data to a persistent place.